# OPA syntax question

Tags: opa

I have seen in the stdlib and in some github project.
Code like that :

```
MyClass =

  field_id(id) = "{id}_field"

{{

my_func(args) = output

}}
```

What the interest to have function before the {{ }} block ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It declares the function as private to the module. Equivalent to:

```
MyClass = {{

  @private
  field_id(id) = "{id}_field"

  my_func(args) = output

}}
```